# My Ubuntu 22.04.2 stuck at 1024x768 resolution

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, intel-graphics, screen

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.04 for the first time and it works well until choosing the resolution; it stuck at 1024x768, and I read some articles on the net, but none of them worked.

```
Hardware           : HP HP ProDesk 600 G2 SFF
processor          : Intel® Core™ i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
Memory             : 8.0 GiB
graphics           : Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
OS                 : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Os Type            : 64-bit
Gnome Version      : 42.5
Windowing system   : Wayland
```

I read about updating the drivers, but this is what appears on the drivers window :

[image: software & updates / addtional drivers]

Comment: Do you have an additional graphics card installed?

Comment: Where is no need in additional driver for integrated video card.